# How to insert data into table which is having new line character in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, external-tables, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Hi I am creating external table which is loading data from S3 Bucket file. But for some column I am getting CRLF due to which data is going to another row and not loading perfectly. Could you please help me how can I resolve this?

Example:

```
Draft recommendation issued to sponsor
"August 23, 2021
To
August 25, 2021"
```

This is loading same into table. How to load the above data into same row.

```
Draft recommendation issued to sponsor
"August 23, 2021 To August 25, 2021"
```

I am using below DDL to insert data into external table-

```
Drop table hta_spectrum.stg_cadth_onco_pharma;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hta_spectrum.stg_cadth_onco_pharma
(

Draft recommendation issued to sponsor VARCHAR(1000)

)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'separatorChar' = '|',
    'quoteChar' = '\"',
    'escapeChar' = '\n'
)
LOCATION 's3://********/Intermediate_layer/onco_pharma/'
TABLE PROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1');
```